# Rebase remote branch onto master while keeping the remote branch updated

Tags: git, rebase, git-remote

I am trying to rebase my remote branch onto master, but I want to keep the remote branch pointing to it's commits, just based at a different point in master.

Here is my structure:

```
A - B - C - D  (origin/master)
 \
  R - S - T (origin/develop)
```

I would like:

```
A  - B - C - D (origin/master) - R - S - T (origin/develop)
```

Is such a rebase possible without some sort of merge?

Comment: why don't you want to just use 'merge' in that case?

Comment: I also want to squash the commits on origin/develop into 1 commit onto origin/master

Comment: In Git, you do all your work on *local* branches. Remote-tracking branches like `origin/develop` just remember for you what your Git saw on `origin`'s Git the last time your Git had a conversation with the Git on `origin`. To make a remote branch change in some way, you must convince that other Git to change it (typically, by making the change locally first, on *your* branches, and then pushing that change).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To see more about rebase you can read [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or write `git rebase --help` at your terminal

To solve your problem there is a easy way, following these steps:

```bash
git branch -D develop          # remove your local develop repository
git fetch //update references 
git checkout develop          # change to develop branch, but because you deleted,
                              # this command will download from origin/develop
git rebase -r origin/master  # -r is --rebase-merges
```

After this step you might have some conflicts, so resolve them and `git add FILES THAT HAD CONFLICTS` and `git rebase --continue`

Now check if everything still working after rebase; if yes

```bash
git push -f origin develop
```

---

**Note:** Prior to v2.35, there was an option `-p` (`--preserve-merges`), which had some slight differences to `-r` but was similar in spirit and function.

Comment: Does this imply that before rebasing, our local repo gets lost and the upstream repo is cloned into local?

Answer (score 4):

In your context, you will do

```
git rebase origin/master    
git rebase origin/master origin/develop
```

**Official reference**: At the beginning

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

after do

```
git rebase master
git rebase master topic
```

we have

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

(Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)